Why isn't Blender editing two poses together?
Blender 3.3.21 (earlier and later) is not editing two dolls to pose together, it only edits one doll only in Pose Mode, but when I add another doll (in Apply) to edit two in one pose (which used to work), the doll does not edit, it only edits one (in Pose Mode).
What do I do?
I need to edit both characters together.


You have selected several objects of different types. Have a look at the outliner at the top right of the screen. There are Lamp.004 and Camera.001, Lamp.005, .... selected. The cannot be posed and "Multi-Pose" mode is blocked because of this. If the active object (the one selected in light-red/orange) is an armature then Blender will put only this object in Pose mode. If the active object is a camera it won't switch the mode. Fix: Deselect all objects (Alt+A or AA), then select only armature objects. Edit mode works the same. You can only multi-edit objects of the same type.
